# How to render callback JSON response in route

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to pass the JSON response `body` to the render function in my route index.js

This is what I have currently and I can't get my head around structuring this so that `body` is accessible in `res.render`

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var request = require('request')

    request.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/get', {
      headers: {'content-type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        consumer_key:'...',
        access_token:'...',
        tag: 'nodejs'
      })
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        // how to pass body to render?
    })

    res.render('index', { 
        title: 'Express', 
        data: body
    });
});
```

Comment: create body as a variable before you make your post, and then simply reuse the variable?

Comment: Add a new route to your render and call that in your callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. Try this

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var request = require('request')

    request.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/get', {
      headers: {'content-type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        consumer_key:'...',
        access_token:'...',
        tag: 'nodejs'
      })
    }, function (err, response, body) {// notice i changed res to response, to differentiate between express response object and request's response
        res.render('index', { 
          title: 'Express',   
          data: body
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: I attempted this before and it complained about res.render typeOf function but strangely this time it works..Is it normal practice to implement request in each route? I originally had this request in a custom module.

Comment: Actually, the issue is there were two `res` variables in your original code. One is from express which has the `render` method and another from request module, which doesnt have `render` method. So, when you access `res` from the callback of `request.post`, it actually pointing to the `res` from `request`. That's why you got that error earlier. Now, since I changed the name of the argument to `response`, it works properly.

Comment: Thanks. Do you normally implement request call in each route? or ideally I need a custom module that implements all the data requests?

Comment: It depends. But, I think a separate module would be lot better in your case. It makes things like "removing the request module altogether and plug some other module instead of request" a lot easier.